# How to work with SVN on windows with Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a repository created for me to keep my projects and now I need to add my files to the repository. The created repository is empty and I need to create `trunk`, `branches` and `tags`. I am using `Tortoise SVN` as the client on Windows for this and no idea how to start with. I am seeing an option to checkout SVN Repo and another option to Import. Which one i need to select and how to create a proper repository structure ?

I have tried creating `trunk` in `Repository Browser` , but it is not showing in my `Windows Explorer`. Is there any user friendly client for SVN on Windows ?

I have been using Git for all my projects and there I have followed the Git-Flow workflow. But here everything seems little messed up or difficult to understand.

Comment: you need to [checkout a working copy where you can add files. Check the help](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html)

Comment: You can use either option. TortoiseSVN is a user friendly client for Windows but you really need a bare minimum knowledge about how Subversion works (for example, [Basic Concepts](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-basics.html)) or, alternatively, try the different options yourself.